# How to sort dataframe based on column whose entries consist of letters and numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'pos': ['A1', 'B03', 'A2', 'B01', 'A3', 'B02'],
        'ignore': range(6)
    }
)
   pos  ignore
0   A1       0
1  A03       1
2   A2       2
3  B01       3
4   B3       4
5  B02       5
```

Which I would like to sort according to `pos` whereby

- it should be first sorted according to the number and then according to the letter and
- leading `0`s should be ignored,

so the desired outcome is

```
   pos  ignore
0   A1       0
1  B01       3
2   A2       2
3  B02       5
4  A03       1
5   B3       4
```

I currently do it like this:

```
df[['let', 'num']] = df['pos'].str.extract(
    '([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)'
)
df['num'] = df['num'].astype(int)
df = (
    df.sort_values(['num', 'let'])
      .drop(['let', 'num'], axis=1)
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

That works, but what I don't like is that I need two temporary columns I later have to drop again. Is there a more straightforward way of doing it?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your method as any other method will need to compute those vlaues in memory anyway.

Comment: I agree with @Datanovice your method is pretty straightforward for a problem which is not.

Comment: @Datanovice: Ok, thanks for the comments. I just tend to introduce temporary columns where they are not required, so I wanted to double-check here :)

Comment: @Erfan: Ok, thanks for the comments. I just tend to introduce temporary columns where they are not required, so I wanted to double-check here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `argsort` with `zfill` and first sort on the numbers as `01, 02, 03` etc. This way you don't have to assign / drop columns:

```
val =  df['pos'].str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)')
df.loc[(val[1].str.zfill(2) + val[0]).argsort()]

   pos  ignore
0   A1       0
3  B01       3
2   A2       2
5  B02       5
4   A3       4
1  B03       1
```

Comment: That's a nice one. Only thing is that I have to know the number for `zfill` (can also be larger than 2), but I guess there I can just use the maximum length of the string in `pos`.

Comment: Yes, `df['pos'].str.len().max() - 1`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```py
import re
def extract_parts(x):
    groups = re.match('([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)', x)
    return (int(groups[2]), groups[1])

df.reindex(df.pos.transform(extract_parts).sort_values().index).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
Out[1]: 
   pos  ignore
0   A1       0
1  B01       3
2   A2       2
3  B02       5
4  A03       1
5   B3       4
```

Comment: Works fine as well, thanks. I need to check how `sort_values` works on tuples; it seems it sorts first on the first entry and then based on the second one (`(3, A)` ends up before `(3, B)`).

Comment: @Cleb You're understanding of sorting based on tuples is correct. You're welcome.